# Azure clr github private repository

Tags: azure, github

I am using the Azure command line tools.

I am running a command like this:

```
azure site create --location "Central US" --github --githubusername "Mygithubusername" --githubpassword "mygithubpassword" --githubrepository "myrepositoryname" Testwebsite
```

If I run this command with a public GitHub repository it works but if I run with a private repository, it says `repository not found`.

If I use the management portal from the browser and go to deployment and login with my GitHub credentials then I can add the private repository too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was going to say you need to provide a password but I see that's part of the command. How are you defining the organization?

Comment: can you paste the whole error message?

Comment: info:    Executing command site create
+ Getting sites
info:    Updating existing site
+ Getting locations
+ Retrieving repositories
info:    Invalid repository {{PrivateRespoitoryName}}
help:    Choose a repository (or hit ctrl-c to exit)
  1) {{PublicRepository}}
  :

Comment: By organization you meant in github? I haven't defined any.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/what-s-the-difference-between-user-and-organization-accounts/ check this out.